# How to fill date range gaps Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

With a given dataset:

```sql
WITH ranges AS (
select to_date('01.01.2021 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') date_from,
    to_date('31.03.2021 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') date_to 
from dual 
union
select to_date('27.03.2021 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') date_from,
    to_date('27.04.2021 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') date_to
from dual 
union
select to_date('01.05.2021 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') date_from,
    to_date('31.12.2021 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') date_to 
from dual 
)
SELECT * FROM ranges;
```

How to find the gap 28.04.2021-30.04.2021.? Also consider that there can be multiple gaps in between and ranges can overlap.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your question asks how to *find* a gap, but the title asks how to *fill* a gap. So it's not clear what you are trying to do. Please edit your question to explain what you want and include your expected output, for more than one set of input data if there are variations that need to be considered. (And preferably include what you've done so far and what issues you are having with your attempt.)

Comment: By the way, `to_date('01.01.2021 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss')` can be written more concisely as `date '2021-01-01'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, tune to your needs:

```
WITH steps AS (
  SELECT date_from as dt, 1 as step FROM ranges
   UNION ALL
  SELECT date_to as dt, -1 as step FROM ranges
)
SELECT dt as dt_from,
       lead(dt) over (order by dt) as dt_to,
       sum(step) over (order by dt) as cnt_ranges
  FROM steps;


dt_from                 | dt_to                   | cnt_ranges
------------------------+-------------------------+-----------
2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-03-27 00:00:00.000 | 1
2021-03-27 00:00:00.000 | 2021-03-31 00:00:00.000 | 2
2021-03-31 00:00:00.000 | 2021-04-27 00:00:00.000 | 1
2021-04-27 00:00:00.000 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00.000 | 0
2021-05-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00.000 | 1
2021-12-31 00:00:00.000 |                         | 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modeling date ranges incorrectly; an interval ending at midnight on 02-14-2021, for example, should **not** include 02-14-2021. In your model it does.

This leads to unnecessary complications in all the queries you write against your model. In the solution below I need to add 1 to end dates first, do all the processing, and then subtract 1 at the end.

```
with
  ranges (date_from, date_to) as (
    select to_date('01.01.2021 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss'),
           to_date('31.03.2021 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
    from   dual
    union  all
    select to_date('27.03.2021 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss'),
           to_date('27.04.2021 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
    from   dual 
    union  all
    select to_date('01.05.2021 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss'),
           to_date('31.12.2021 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
    from   dual 
)
select first_missing, last_missing - 1 as last_missing
from   (
         select dt                          as first_missing, 
                lead(df) over (order by dt) as last_missing
         from   (select date_from, date_to + 1 as date_to from ranges)
         match_recognize(
           order by date_from
           measures first(date_from) as df, max(date_to) as dt
           pattern  (a* b)
           define   a as max(date_to) >= next (date_from)
         )
       )
where  last_missing is not null
;

FIRST_MISSING       LAST_MISSING       
------------------- -------------------
28.04.2021 00:00:00 30.04.2021 00:00:00
```